# Look for patterns in the keys of an array, to group them in a new array

Tags: php, array, parsing

I am working on a function that will take a an array of options. These options are retrived from a database, and could have other options inputted throughout the system. When adding my options, I am constrained by only being able to add a single option at a time. I can't currently add an array of options. The options that the system adds can be unpredictable, because of the codebase. The resulting array from the database call could look like this, except for the option keys I define starting with `custom_`, those I can rely on being there, since I set them:

```
array(
    0 => '...',
    'menu_items' => array(
        'item1' => '...',
        'item2' => '...',
        'item3' => '...',
        'item4' => '...',
    ),
    'another_item'                  => '...',
    'custom_contact_office_name'           => 'The Office Name',
    'custom_contact_office_address'        => '1234 Address St',
    'custom_contact_office_phone'          => '555.555.5555',
    'custom_contact_office_email'          => 'email@domain.com',
    'custom_contact_office_fax'            => '555.555.5555',
    'custom_contact_office_leader_name'    => 'Mr. Pickles',
    'custom_contact_office_leader_address' => '5678 Address St',
    'custom_contact_office_leader_phone'   => '555.555.5555',
    'custom_contact_office_leader_email'   => 'personal@domain.com',
    'custom_social_linkedin'               => 'linkedin.com/profile_url',
    'custom_social_facebook'               => 'facebook.com/profile_url',
    'custom_social_twitter'                => 'twitter.com/profile_url',
    'custom_social_gplus'                  => 'google.com/plus/profile_url',
    'custom_social_github'                 => 'github.com/profile_url',
    'custom_social_youtube'                => 'youtube.com/profile_url',
    'another_option'                => '...',
    'some_other_kind_of_option'     => '...',
    'some_more_items_of_this'       => '...',
);
```

The way the system works is to serialize all the options in one array and save it to the db table. So you have to register the option by "id" which is really just used as the key in the massive serialized array that gets saved, so it needs to be unique, thus all the prefixes. I'm not interested in the other defined options, in fact, I want to skip over them while parsing through the array. So I wrote a couple functions to parse the `office` section:

```
/**
 * Parse the settings passed in
 *
 * @param $main_pattern
 * @param $sub_pattern
 * @param $option_name
 * @param $option_value
 *
 * @return null
 */
function setting_parser($main_pattern, $sub_pattern, $option_name, $option_value) {
    if (preg_match( $main_pattern, $option_name )) {
        if (preg_match( $sub_pattern, $option_name )) {
            return $option_value;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

/**
 * Apply the values to the multi-dimensional array
 * 
 * @param array  $theme_options
 * @param array  $info_types
 * @param string $section
 * @param string $section_pattern
 * @param bool  $is_option_string
 * 
 * @return array
 */
function apply_multi_dimensional_values(array $theme_options, array $info_types, $section, $section_pattern, $is_option_string) {
    $array_ref = array();
    foreach ($theme_options as $option_name => $option_value) {
        if ($is_option_string && preg_match( '/custom/', $option_name )) {
            /* Check if it's a string, to avoid numerically indexed values */
            if ( is_string( $option_name ) ) {
                if ($info_types !== null && is_array( $info_types )) {
                    for ($i = 0; $i<count( $info_types ); $i++) {
                        if (preg_match( sprintf( '/%s/', $info_types[ $i ] ), $option_name ) && preg_match( $section_pattern, $option_name )) {
                            $array_ref[$section][$info_types[$i]] = setting_parser( $section_pattern, sprintf( '/%s/', $info_types[$i] ), $option_name, $option_value );
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            if ($info_types !== null && is_array( $info_types ) && preg_match( '/custom/', $option_name )) {
                for ($i = 0; $i<count( $info_types ); $i++) {
                    if (preg_match( sprintf( '/%s/', $info_types[ $i ] ), $option_name ) && preg_match( $section_pattern, $option_name )) {
                        $array_ref[$section][$info_types[$i]] = setting_parser( $section_pattern, sprintf( '/%s/', $info_types[$i] ), $option_name, $option_value );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $array_ref;
}
/**
 * Get the office info
 *
 * @param array $theme_options
 * @param bool  $is_option_string
 *
 * @return array
 * @throws Exception
 */
function get_office_info(array $theme_options, $is_option_string = true) {
    $info_types = array(
        'name',
        'address',
        'phone',
        'email',
        'fax'
    );
    // if leader does NOT come after office, but it in office array
    // uses positive look-ahead
    $section_pattern = '/office_(?!leader)/';
    $section = 'office';

    if (empty( $theme_options )) throw new Exception("First argument MUST be a valid array.");

    $office_info = apply_multi_dimensional_values( $theme_options, $info_types, $section, $section_pattern, $is_option_string );

    return $office_info;
}

/**
 * @param array $theme_options
 * @param bool  $is_option_string
 *
 * @return array
 * @throws Exception
 */
function get_leader_info(array $theme_options, $is_option_string = true) {
    $info_types = array(
        'name',
        'address',
        'phone',
        'email'
    );
    // If leader comes after office, put it in leader array
    // uses negative look-ahead
    $section_pattern = '/(office_(?=leader))/';
    $section = 'leader';

    if (empty( $theme_options )) throw new Exception("First argument MUST be a valid array.");

    $leader_info = apply_multi_dimensional_values( $theme_options, $info_types, $section, $section_pattern, $is_option_string );

    return $leader_info;
}
```

The purpose of parsing these arrays is to basically group them into the relevant data. I group them by a section key that I pass into both the `get_office_info()` function and the `get_leader_info()` function. The bit of code handling this looks like this:

```
$array_ref[$section][$info_types[$i]] = ...
```

So that the result of calling `get_office_info()` will be an array like this:

```
'office' => array(
    'name'    => 'The Office Name',
    'address' => '1234 Address St',
    'phone'   => '555.555.5555',
    'email'   => 'email@domain.com',
    'fax'     => '555.555.5555'
)
```

The result of calling `get_leader_info()` will be an array like this:

```
'leader' => array(
    'name'    => 'Mr. Pickles',
    'address' => '5678 Address St',
    'phone'   => '555.555.5555',
    'email'   => 'personal@domain.com'
)
```

**I just can't help but feeling like there's a cleaner way to do this that I am missing, or don't have enough experience to recognize.** I am doing a similar thing with social, but it's different because it will be a single-dimensional, numerically indexed array containing a social profile link that I can just loop through. If the clean-up for this solution doesn't kill both birds, I will post that as a seperate code review.

The calling goes like this `get_(office|leader)_info()` -> `apply_multi_dimensional_values()` -> `setting_parser()` which will get called in a loop.

The part in particular that I am concerned about is all the logic inside the `apply_multi_dimensional_values()` function. Please let me know if you need any more information to review the code.

Comment: Are you sure that your code do what you want it to do?. There are too many strange things.

Comment: The underlying problem here is that you're using arrays for everything. Use objects for starters. Then, address ***how the data is being fetched***. Clearly, the data is returned/loaded in a format that requires intense processing just to get it to a usable state. Rather than re-formatting the data, why not fix the data source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think It will be much easer to get required options if you

1. Create array with keys that you need (where key is full key name in `theme_options`).
2. Then walk over `theme_options` and fill values in these arrays.
3. Remove unneeded prefix from keys in arrays.

Check this:

```
/**
 * @param string $prefix
 * @param array $endings
 * @param array $theme_options
 */
function find_opts_with_prefix( $prefix, array $endings, array $theme_options ){
    /*
      return array with theme options which key is equal to $prefix.$ending (for each ending in enginds).
     */

    $required_keys = Array(); //create keys array
    foreach( $endings as $end ){
        $required_keys[ $prefix . $end ] = null;
    }

    foreach( $theme_options as $key => $value ){ //fill value if key exists
        if( array_key_exists( $required_values[ $key ] ) )
            $required_values[ $key ] = $value;
    }

    $not_null = function( $value ){ return $value !== null; } ;
    return array_filter( $required_values, $not_null ); //filter out null values
}

/**
 *  @param string $prefix
 *  @param array $options
 */
function remove_prefix( $prefix, array $options ){
    /*
      remove prefix form every option  
      return new array with options without prefix
     */
    $result_opts = Array();
    $prefix_len = str_len( $prefix );
    foreach( $options as $key => $value ){
        $result_opts[ substr( $key, $prefix_len ) ] = $value;
    }
    return $result_opts;
}


/**
 * @param string $prefix
 * @param array $info_types
 * @param array $theme_options
 */
function get_infos( $prefix, array $info_types, array $theme_options) {

    $found_types = find_opts_with_prefix( $prefix, $info_types, $theme_options );
    return remove_prefix( $fountd_types );
}

function is_custom_option( $option_name ){
    return strncmp( $option_name, 'custom_', 7 );
}

function group_options( array $theme_options ){
    /* 
       This method will build your 
       $array_ref[$section][$info_types[$i]] 
    */

    if (empty( $theme_options )) 
         throw new Exception("First argument MUST be a valid array.");

    //define sections and info types.
    $info_types = Array( 'offise' => Array( 'name',
                                            'address',
                                            'phone',
                                            'email',
                                            'fax' ),

                         'leader' => Array( 'name',
                                            'address',
                                            'phone',
                                            'email' ) );

    // prefixes, like "custom_contact_office", and sections 
    // better put into array with info_types.
    // but i was too lazy.

    $custom_opts = array_filter( $theme_options, 'is_custom_option' );

    $array_refs = Array();
    $array_refs['office'] = get_infos( 'custom_contact_office', $info_types['office'], $custom_opts );
    $array_refs['leader'] = get_infos( 'custom_contact_office_leader', $info_types['leader'], $custom_opts );
    return $array_refs;
}
```

Comment: This answer helped me the best. I dropped this into [PHPFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/) and after working through the PHP errors, which I expected with example code, I just wanted to point something out I ran into: `is_custom_option()`, which is the callback for [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) was getting passed the value of the array, not the key. But **as of PHP 5.6** they introduced the `ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY` as well as `ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH`, which helped. Thank you for your review, I learned a lot! A lot more elegant than my solution.

Answer (score 2):

1. Redundant `is_string` check.

   ```
   if ($is_option_string && preg_match( '/custom/', $option_name )) {
       /* Check if it's a string, to avoid numerically indexed values */
         if ( is_string( $option_name ) ) {  // <==
   ```

   If variable `option_name` matches with `/custom/` then it is string.
2. Inner loops are same: extract code to function, and use `foreach` instead of `for`. 
   (This is first 'strange' part of your code).
3. After code extraction, you will see that first two `if`'s are useless, parameter `is_option_string` don't do anything. (Second strange part).

   ```
   // this code    
   if ($is_option_string && preg_match( '/custom/', $option_name )) {
           if ($info_types !== null && is_array( $info_types )) {
                 /*call extracted func here */
           }
   } else {
           if ($info_types !== null && is_array( $info_types ) && preg_match( '/custom/', $option_name )) { /*extracted func*/ }
   }

   // is equivalent to

   $info_is_ok = $info_types !== null && is_array( $info_types );
   $match_exists = preg_match( '/custom/', $option_name );
   if ($is_option_string && $match_exists && $info_is_ok ){
       /*call extracted func*/ 
   } elseif ( $info_is_ok && $match_exists) { 
       /*call extracted func*/ 
   }
   //doesn't metter what in $is_option_string, 
   //extracted function will be called if match exists and info_type is ok.
   ```
4. If `info_type` is null or not `Array` then `foreach` loop won't do anything

Answer (score 1):

I question the whole persistence model. Rather than explore ways to write code to work around what looks to be a bad data storage model, I would think about how you can best persist the data in an appropriate manner such that it can be read into your application without an intervening layer of regex-based data mapping.

Comment: +1 Yeah, you and me both! However, with legacy systems that's not always the solution the bosses are looking for in the middle of a project. Best to re-visit it later.

Comment: @mrclean208: Bosses sometimes need devs to tell them that, if they don't want to be faced with issues in the future (ie clients being unhappy because of bugs, potential loss of revenue as a result, and lots of hours wasted on refactoring), that it's worth it to bite the bullet earlier rather than later. I honestly believe that you're trying to find a solution for a problem that shouldn't exist. Fix problems at their source...